# Download Svelte error: Ok to proceed? (y) cd my-app svelte

Tags: javascript, terminal, svelte

I am trying to download svelte. When I write:

```
npm create svelte@latest my-app
cd my-app
npm install
npm run dev -- --open
```

I get the message and I can't press yes:

> Ok to proceed? (y) cd my-app svelte

with the following error:

[image: Error]

I have tried to turn on and off my mac, and I have downloaded node.js.

Can someone please help me? :)

Comment: You have multiple commands in one go. Execute in separate them: `npm create svelte@latest my-app`, `cd my-app`, `npm install npm run dev -- --open`

Answer (score 0):

Install latest stable version of node.js (includes npm):

https://nodejs.org/en/